# Using preg_replace and regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in PHP

```
$content="<a some_text> {pr_start} some_text</a> <a other_text>{pr_stop}</a>
          <a some_text> {pr_start} </a> <a some_text> {pr_start} </a>";
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of the substring

```
"<a some_text> {pr_start}  some_text</a>"
```

with text `"START"` and leave the rest as it is!

The result expected is:

```
"START <a other_text>{pr_stop}</a> START START"
```

I used

```
preg_replace('#<a(.*)({pr_start})(.*)</a>#',"START",$content);
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an ungreedy flag `U` in your pattern:

```
preg_replace('#<a(.*)({pr_start})(.*)</a>#U',"START",$content);
```